# Training a Machine Learning predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, language-features, feature-selection

I have been trying to build a prediction model using a user’s data. Model’s input is documents’ metadata (date published, title etc) and document label is that user’s preference (like/dislike). I would like to ask some questions that I have come across hoping for some answers:

1. There are way more liked documents than disliked. I read somewhere that if somebody train’s a model using way more inputs of one label than the other this affects the performance in a bad way (model tends to classify everything to the label/outcome that has the majority of inputs
2. Is there possible to have input to a ML algorithm e.g logistic regression be hybrid in terms of numbers and words and how that could be done, sth like:

   input = [18,23,1,0,’cryptography’] with  label = [‘Like’]

   Also can we use a vector ( that represents a word, using tfidf etc) as an input feature (e.g. 50-dimensions vector) ?
3. In order to construct a prediction model using textual data the only way to do so is by deriving a dictionary out of every word mentioned in our documents and then construct a binary input that will dictate if a term is mentioned or not? Using such a version though we lose the weight of the term in the collection right?
   Can we use something as a word2vec vector as a single input in a supervised learning model?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You either need to under-sample the bigger class (take a small random sample to match the size of the smaller class), over-sample the smaller class (bootstrap sample), or use an algorithm that supports unbalanced data - and for that you'll need to read the documentation.
2. You need to turn your words into a word vector. Columns are all the unique words in your corpus. Rows are the documents. Cell values are one of: whether the word appears in the document, the number of times it appears, the relative frequency of its appearance, or its TFIDF score. You can then have these columns along with your other non-word columns.

Now you probably have more columns than rows, meaning you'll get a singularity with matrix-based algorithms, in which case you need something like SVM or Naive Bayes.